# What does this code do? (awk)

Tags: linux, awk

here I have a part of my awk code to parse a file but the output is not 100% what I want.

```
match($0,/root=[^,]*/){
        n=split(substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5),N,/:/)
```

My Problem is that I can not tell by 100% what this piece of code is exactly doing ... 
Can someone just tell me what this two lines exactly do?

EDIT:
I just want to know what the code does so I can fix it myself, so please do not ask something like: how the file you parse looks like? ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> match(s, r [, a])
>
> Returns the position in s where the regular expression r occurs, or 0
>   if r is not present, and sets the values of RSTART and RLENGTH. Note
>   that the argument order is the same as for the ~ operator: str ~ re.
>   If array a is provided, a is cleared and then elements 1 through n are
>   filled with the portions of s that match the corresponding
>   parenthesized subexpression in r. The 0'th element of a contains the
>   portion of s matched by the entire regular expression r. Subscripts
>   a[n, "start"], and a[n, "length"] provide the starting index in the
>   string and length respectively, of each matching substring.
>
> substr(s, i [, n])
>
> Returns the at most n-character substring of s starting at i. If n is
>   omitted, the rest of s is used.
>
> split(s, a [, r])
>
> Splits the string s into the array a on the regular expression r, and
>   returns the number of fields. If r is omitted, FS is used instead. The
>   array a is cleared first. Splitting behaves identically to field
>   splitting, described above.

So when match finds something that matches `/root=[^,]*/` in the line (`$0`) it will return that position (non-zero integers are truth-y for awk) and the action will execute.

The action then uses `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` as set by `match` to get the substring of the line that matched (minus `root=` because of the `+5`/`-5`) and then splits that into the array `N` on `:` and saves the number of fields split into `n`.

That could probably be changed to `match($0, /root=([^,]*)/, N)` as the pattern and then use `N[1,"start"]` in the action instead of `substr` if you wanted.

Comment: thank you, great answer but what does change when lets say I set RSTART to +10 and RLENGTH to-10?

Comment: From `man awk` --> The  index  of  the  first character matched by match(); 0 if no match.  (This implies that character indices start at one.)

Comment: @howdoesthiswork Assign them those values or change the offsets by those values? I'm going to assume you mean change the offsets. In which case the result from `substr` will just start five characters later into the matched string. Try it and find out. `print substr($0, RSTART+10, RLENGTH-10)'